# Pronunciation of the name "Kyrylo"

Tags: pronunciation, names

Can someone provide a transcription for the name "Kyrylo" - how it will actually sound?

Comment: Is there someone famous this applies to? Otherwise this question seems to localised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keer-əl-oh.  (ə is the schwa, an attenuated "uh" sound.)

Answer (score 2):

You might think about calling yourself Cyril in English-speaking countries.  Quite a few people will find "Kyrylo" strange and hard to pronounce, where Cyril is quite common.  (You may not be able to get used to the soft C, of course, in which case just ignore me).

Comment: The problem is that I can't change it in my documents. In my native language everything is OK, but our government approved new stupid transliteration for passports for traveling abroad.

Comment: I see the problem, but even immigration officials should accept "Kyrylo, pronounced Cyril" (if that's what you want).

Answer (score 1):

What language is your native? You know that names is specific words, that sounds as it sounds at place where it appeared. So in Ukrainian it sounds like [kirilo] and if you want just transcription а this word you can use Google translator http://translate.google.com.ua/#en|ru|Kyrylo

Comment: I looked at Ukrainians law about transliteration ukrainian to english. So my name will be "Kyrylo" in passport for traveling abroad. I wanted to know how actually people will appeal to me :)

Comment: I think it would sounds [kirilo] no matter what.

Comment: that's why im asked native english spelling people :) But thank you anyway.